# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey' to 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.IssuerSigningKeyResolver'

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to working with C#. I am working on a course using it for the first time. I am following the Neil Cummings course on building an app with asp.netcore and angular. I get a CS0029, I understand that I am returning the wrong type, what I do not understand is how to fix/remove the error?
my code:
the error happens by 'IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricKey...'

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace API.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class IdentityServiceExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"])), //error here
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
            };
        });

        return services;
        }
```

It is also my first time using Stackoverflow, so I hope I have posted my question correctly?

Many thanks for the assistance in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found that simply removing `resolver` from `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` eliminated the error completely, and my code was able to work again.
I think the course was not fully updated, as it does not cover this.